# Matlab comapring values of one row

Tags: matlab

I have a row of recurring values and I want to compare them with one another. For example, the first value is compared with the whole row and if there is a match it's saved in one variable; if not, then a new variable is created. Similarly, the second value will be compared, and so on.

I cant seem to work it out. Example:

```
  A=[5.34
     1.20
     4.54
     3.68
     5.34
     4.54]
```

I want the same values to be stored in one variable and the next values like 1.20 to be stored in another variable, and so on

Comment: Your desired output is unclear. State *explicitly* the output you want from the vector `A` provided.

Comment: So you want the [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) values in the array? (Although I recommend using [`uniquetol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html) with floating-point values.)